# Cannot read properties of undefined in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to do a sample register without JWT using MVC in nodejs, express and mysql so when I run my code and I have an error :

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName') at exports.register

here is my code :

**AuthController**

```
const AuthModel = require('../models/Auth')

// Create and Save a new User
exports.register = (req, res) => {
  // Validate request
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Content can not be empty!"
    });
  }

  // Create user
  const user = new AuthModel({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  // Save user in the database
  AuthModel.createUser(user, (err, data) => {
    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while registring."
      });
    else res.send(data);
  });
};
```

**AuthModel**

```
const AuthModel = function(table){
   
    this.firstName = table.firstName;
    this.lastName = table.lastName;
    this.email = table.email;
    this.password = table.password;

}

AuthModel.createUser = ( newUser, result ) =>{

        db.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", newUser, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("error: ", err);
              result(err, null);
              return;
            }
        
            console.log("User are registed: ", { id: res.insertId, ...newUser });
            result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...newUser });
          });
        };
```

Comment: You should try to debug using console.log(req.body) and see what is missing. and you check only if the req.body is present, not that it contains an objects with firstname, email, ... keys

Comment: I checked the req.body and is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me as if the req.body is undefined. I think you might need something like body-parser, which has been added into the core of Express starting with version 4.

Try adding this middleware to your entrypoint: `app.use(express.json());`

See more here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Comment: thank you thats the right answer I just add it in the wrong line

Answer (score 0):

In your `exports.register`, you `.send()` if the body is undefined. That doesn't mean the rest of the code won't be executed.

Replace:

```
res.status(400).send({
   message: "Content can not be empty!"
});
```

by

```
return res.status(400).send({
   message: "Content can not be empty!"
});
```

Comment: yeah it should because it cannot read properties of req.body

Comment: That's what I meant. Your code does what it should, you simply forgot to end its execution by adding a return. That doesn't explain and won't fix WHY your body is undefined though.